System of N linear equations for a Vandermonde matrix
Let $V_N$ to be a squared Vandermonde matrix of the form:
$V_N = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & \dots & 1 \\
x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & \dots & x_N \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
x_1^{N-1} & x_2^{N-1} & x_3^{N-1} & \dots & x_N^{N-1}
\end{pmatrix}$.
I want to solve the following system of $N$ linear equations $V_NY=0$, where $Y=\begin{pmatrix}
y_1 \\
y_2 \\
\vdots \\
y_N
\end{pmatrix}$. Is it correct that the general solution for the $k$-th term is:
$\prod_{j=1,j\neq k}^N(x_k-x_j)y_k=0$? Or am I missing something here?
Thank you!
